# Can use a nested dict in urlib.encode- python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have a api url.
http://10.236.220.130:5056/api/v1/viewentities?where={"EntityId":"srv-1499839282322"}
my search query variable/key is where={"EntityId":"srv-1499839282322"}
this is my code in python 2.7

```
tgt="srv-1499839282322"
baseurl="http://10.236.220.130:5056/api/v1/viewentities?"`enter code here`
values={"where": '{"EntityId": "srv-1499839282322"}'}
```

(if i hardcode this srv stuff above it works)

```
encode=urllib.urlencode(values)
url=baseurl + encode
print encode
```

Note the url which am getting is working but my condition is, i want that srv stuff to be a variable that will come as one of my function parameter.

================
I tried this these

```
tgt="srv-1499839282322"
baseurl="http://10.236.220.130:5056/api/v1/viewentities?"
value={"where": {}}
value["where"]["EntityId"]=tgt
encode=urllib.urlencode(values)
url=baseurl + encode
print encode
```

But this encode url is not working...what i found is the 
the urlparse.urlencode takes the query as a dictionary and my value as itself is a dictionary. (nested)
if print values(working) and value(not working)
i find the single quotes are the one missing from value.

{'where': {'EntityId': 'srv-1499839282322'}}-----> not working
{'where': '{"EntityId": "srv-1499839282322"}'} ----> working